# Springfox Swagger 2.9.2 Incredibly Slow with Spring Boot 2.5.x With Groovy 3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a Spring Boot 2.4.4 project with Springfox 2.9.2.  When I upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.3, my servers cannot start: the Swagger scanning takes forever and a day and (I think) exhausts the heap.

I turn on the logger `springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.parameter.ModelAttributeParameterExpander` and filter on messages like `Expanding parameter type`. On the old configuration (Boot 2.4.4, Groovy 2.15.x), I get 530 DEBUG messages.  When I upgrade to Boot 2.5.3/Groovy 3, I get 377,748 DEBUG log messages.

In the good case, the types in those log messages are the types in my web API. For the bad config, I get the kitchen sink (this is a tiny sample):

```
Expanding parameter type: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression>
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression>
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocTag
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode>
Expanding parameter type: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocTag>
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocHolder
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode>
Expanding parameter type: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotatedNode
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocTag
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocHolder
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImportNode>
Expanding parameter type: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.PackageNode
Expanding parameter type: groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<groovy.lang.groovydoc.GroovydocTag>
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImportNode>
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ImportNode>
Expanding parameter type: java.security.cert.CertPath
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Iterator<java.lang.String>
Expanding parameter type: java.security.cert.CertPath
Expanding parameter type: java.util.Iterator<java.lang.String>
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<java.security.cert.Certificate>
Expanding parameter type: byte[]
Expanding parameter type: java.security.cert.Certificate
Expanding parameter type: byte[]
Expanding parameter type: java.security.PublicKey
Expanding parameter type: java.security.cert.Certificate
Expanding parameter type: byte[]
Expanding parameter type: java.security.PublicKey
Expanding parameter type: java.security.CodeSigner
Expanding parameter type: java.security.Timestamp
Expanding parameter type: java.security.cert.Certificate[]
Expanding parameter type: java.security.CodeSigner[]
Expanding parameter type: java.util.List<org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode>
Expanding parameter type: java.security.CodeSource
Expanding parameter type: java.net.URL
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.Package
Expanding parameter type: java.net.URL
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]
Expanding parameter type: java.lang.reflect.Parameter
```

The relevant parts of the POM should be:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-dateutil</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-datetime</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-templates</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <classifier>indy</classifier>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, can provide your pom.xml plesae?

Comment: Added relevant parts of pom